# typescript require (node) with type

Tags: typescript

I am experimenting with a electron application written in typescript. I am trying to found out 
what the correct implementation is for requiring an external module.

My typescript config is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "outDir": "../build"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser"
  ]
}
```

I have 2 classes, each in its own file.

```
class person {
    private job: job;
    public setJob(name: string) {
        this.job = new job(name);
    }
}

class job {
    private name: string;
    constructor(name : string) {
        var externalTool = require('external-tool');
        //Do stuff with external tool.
    }
}
```

And a ts file for the external tool:

```
declare module ExternalTool {
    interface Something {
        doSomethingWithName(name:string): string;
    }
}

declare module "external-tool" {
    export = ExternalTool;
}
```

require is definded by 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts'

Currently 'externalTool' variable is of the type 'any'. How do I get typescript to recognize it as the correct type.
I could replace the require with "import externalTool = require('external-tool')" but then the person class no longer recognizes the job class.

So what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems I was somewhat of track with how to go about using typescript in multiple files.

After some googling, and getting to understand it better my solution was to correctly set the export values. And then import them in the file I need them in.

person.ts

```
import job = require('./job');
class person {
    private job: job;
    public setJob(name: string) {
        this.job = new job(name);
    }
}
export = person;
```

job.ts

```
import externalTool = require('external-tool');
class job {
    private name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
      //  var externalTool = require('external-tool');
        //Do stuff with external tool.
    }
}
export = job;
```

For some weird reason I thought typescript would do this automagicly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `import externalTool = require('external-tool');` at the top of the file that contains your `job` class, and fix whatever it is that is causing your `the person class no longer recognizes the job class` issue. Your `ExternalTool` stuff is in a `.d.ts` file right?